# Transfer data attributes from option tags to UI selectmenu items

Tags: jquery, select-menu, jquery-ui-selectmenu

I need to transfer all data-attributes from option tags to to UI selectmenu items (li tags). How do this with API ?

```
<select class="select" id="" name="PROPERTY[126]">
  <option value="315" data-filter="flat">Квартира</option>
  <option value="316" data-show="standart" data-filter="room">Комната</option>
  <option value="317" data-filter="house" data-hide="standart flat room uchastok" data-show="house zarub elite">Коттедж</option>
  <option value="318" data-filter="uchastok" data-show="zarub uchastok elite" data-hide="standart flat room house">Участок</option>
  <option value="319" data-filter="zarub" data-show="elite" data-hide="standart">Зарубежная недвижимость</option>
</select>

<script>$("select").selectmenu()</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

add this to your code and data attributes will copy:

```
$.widget( "ui.selectmenu", $.ui.selectmenu, {
   _renderItem: function( ul, item ) {
        elementdata = item.element.context.dataset;
        attributesObj = {};
        Object.keys(elementdata).forEach(function(x){
            attributesObj["data-"+x] = elementdata[x]; 
        });
        return $( '<li>' )
         .attr(attributesObj)
            .append(item.label)
            .appendTo( ul );
   } 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution:

```
var select = $("#selectid");
var $ul = $("<ul></ul>").appendTo("body");

select.find("option").each(function(i){
    var $li = $("<li></li>").appendTo($ul);
    $li.text($(this).text());
    $li.data($(this).data());
});
```

And a working **demo**: http://jsfiddle.net/gds9xkkm/

Comment: thanks, but this is custom method. I need to do this by using JQuery UI Selectmenu API (_renderMenu).. Do you know how do this?

Comment: Please provide more information about that plugin for me to understand what you want to accomplish and how can I help

Comment: I'm try do this $( "select" ).selectmenu({ icons: { button: "ui-icon-triangle-1-s" },
                           
                           _renderItem: function( ul, item ) {
                                          var li = $( "<li>" )
                                            .data( "show", item.value );
                                          this._setText( li, item.label );
                                         
                                          return li.appendTo( ul );
                                        }         
              });

Answer (score 0):

Hope below code may help you :)

test Link :http://jsfiddle.net/jzw4139p/embedded/result/

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>selectmenu demo</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.2/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.2/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>  
  </head>
  <body>

    <select class="select" id="speed" name="PROPERTY[126]">
      <option value="315" data-filter="flat">Квартира</option>
      <option value="316" data-filter="room" data-show="standart">Комната</option>
      <option value="317" data-filter="house" data-hide="standart flat room uchastok" data-show="house zarub elite">Коттедж</option>
      <option value="318" data-filter="uchastok" data-show="zarub uchastok elite" data-hide="standart flat room house">Участок</option>
      <option value="319" data-filter="zarub" data-show="elite" data-hide="standart">Зарубежная недвижимость</option>
    </select>
    <script>
      $.widget( "ui.selectmenu", $.ui.selectmenu, {
           _renderItem: function( ul, item ) {
              return $( '<li>' )
                 .attr({
                    'data-value': item.value ,
                    'data-filter':$(item.element).data('filter'),
                    'data-show': $(item.element).data('show'),
                    'data-hide': $(item.element).data('hide')

                  })
                 .append(item.label)
                 .appendTo( ul );
           } 
        });
      $("#speed").selectmenu({
        change: function( event, ui ) {
          alert("data-filter is : "+$(ui.item.element).data('filter')+" value is  : "+ui.item.value);
        }
      });
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```