# Add class to jQuery UI selectmenu <li> from original <option>

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I'm looking to copy the custom classes added to the initial < option > over to the jQuery selectmenu UI generated list. I've tried using 'transferClasses: true' but that just transfers the main  class across.

The select menu markup before jQuery UI is:

```
<select>
    <option>Option 1</option>
    <option>Option 2</option>
    <option class="child-option">Sub Option 1</option>
    <option class="child-option">Sub Option 2</option>
    <option>Option 3</option>
    ...
</select>
```

---

EDIT: What jQuery UI outputs at the moment:

```
<div class="ui-selectmenu-menu">
    <ul>
        <li class="ui-menu-item"><div>Option 1</div></li>
        <li class="ui-menu-item"><div>Option 2</div></li>
        <li class="ui-menu-item"><div>Sub Option 1</div></li>
        <li class="ui-menu-item"><div>Sub Option 2</div></li>
        <li class="ui-menu-item"><div>Option 3</div></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

---

What I'd like jQuery UI to output:

```
<div class="ui-selectmenu-menu">
    <ul>
        <li class="ui-menu-item"><div>Option 1</div></li>
        <li class="ui-menu-item"><div>Option 2</div></li>
        <li class="ui-menu-item child-option"><div>Sub Option 1</div></li>
        <li class="ui-menu-item child-option"><div>Sub Option 2</div></li>
        <li class="ui-menu-item"><div>Option 3</div></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

I've tried the solutions in similar request threads [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27348549/transfer-data-attributes-from-option-tags-to-ui-selectmenu-items) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41570175/how-set-individual-styles-css-for-option-in-selectmenu-jquery-ui-selectmenu) but with no success.

---

EDIT 2:

The jQuery I'm using to generate the `ul` is:

```
$( "select" ).selectmenu({
    transferClasses: true,
});
```

---

Any help would be great!

Thanks

Comment: Is the class being copied to all the `li` or just the ones that are the same index as the options?

Comment: Ideally to be the same list items as the select options. So in the example, only the third and fourth list items would get the class.

Comment: It's unclear how you're going from the `select` to the `ul`. Is that something that the jQuery UI is automatically doing or are you manually recreating it?

Comment: I'm using jQuery UI's selectmenu widget from here http://api.jqueryui.com/selectmenu/ to get the `ul` from the manual select menu

Comment: I don't see the `transferClasses` option on the docs http://api.jqueryui.com/selectmenu/

Comment: I didn't either but some other threads suggested to use it. Either way, all that does it pull the class from the `select` and applies it to the `ul` which isn't quite what I was looking for.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I was able to do it by looping over the newly created select menu using the open event. Apparently the actual items don't exist until the first time the open method is called.

```js
$('select').selectmenu({
  open: function() {
      $('div.ui-selectmenu-menu li.ui-menu-item').each(function(idx){
      $(this).addClass( $('select option').eq(idx).attr('class') )
      })
  }
})
```

```css
.child-option {
  background:red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<select>
  <option>Option 1</option>
  <option>Option 2</option>
  <option class="child-option">Sub Option 1</option>
  <option class="child-option">Sub Option 2</option>
  <option>Option 3</option>
</select>
```

Comment: I was going to suggest something more complicated, so good job. You could probably use http://api.jqueryui.com/selectmenu/#method-_renderItem as well.

Comment: That works a charm, thank you @j08691! Thanks for the input too @american-slime

Answer (score 2):

It seems there no way you can instruct selectmenu to preserve classes or other attributes.

But you can create your own selectmenu extension via widget factory.

```js
//classyMenu widget extends/overrides selectmenu
$.widget("custom.classyMenu", $.ui.selectmenu, { 
  _renderItem: function(ul, item) {
    var li = $("<li>" ,{
      class: item.element.attr("class") //access the original item's class
    }),
    wrapper = $("<div>", {
      text: item.label
    });
    if ( item.disabled ) {
      li.addClass("ui-state-disabled");
    }
    return li.append( wrapper ).appendTo(ul);
  }
});


$("select").classyMenu(); //use classyMenu instad of selectmenu()

$("#open").click(function(){
  $("select").classyMenu("open");
});

$("#close").click(function(){
  $("select").classyMenu("close");
});
```

```css
.bronze{color: #D1A684;}
.silver{color: silver;}
.gold{color: gold;}

ui-selectmenu-button{font-weight: bold}
```

```html
<link href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script
  src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-VazP97ZCwtekAsvgPBSUwPFKdrwD3unUfSGVYrahUqU="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<button id="open">Open</button>
<button id="close">Close</button>

<br />

<select>
  <option value=""></option>
  <option value="1" class="bronze">1</option>
  <option value="2" class="silver">2</option>
  <option value="3" class="gold">3</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a simple and direct way to add custom class to any jQuery UI widget - it's [classes option](http://learn.jquery.com/jquery-ui/widget-factory/classes-option/).

Let's take a simple case with [selectmenu](https://jqueryui.com/selectmenu/#default) jQuery widget.

HTML part is strict:

```
<select name="speed" id="speed" class="my-happy-decorated-class">
  <option>Slower</option>
  <option>Slow</option>
  <option selected="selected">Medium</option>
  <option>Fast</option>
  <option>Faster</option>
</select>
```

As usual, in order to decorate this ugly default stuff with cute jQuery UI just afterwards the document has been loaded we apply appropriate for the widget jQuery UI-function **selectmenu()**:

```
<script>
  $(function() {
      $("#speed").selectmenu();
  } );
</script>
```

As a result we get something like this:

```
<select name="speed" id="speed" style="display: none;" class="my-happy-decorated-class">
            <option>Slower</option>
            <option>Slow</option>
            <option selected="selected">Medium</option>
            <option>Fast</option>
            <option>Faster</option>
        </select>
<span tabindex="0" id="speed-button" role="combobox" aria-expanded="false" aria-autocomplete="list" aria-owns="speed-menu" aria-haspopup="true" class="ui-selectmenu-button ui-button ui-widget ui-selectmenu-button-closed ui-corner-all" aria-activedescendant="ui-id-3" aria-labelledby="ui-id-3" aria-disabled="false"><span class="ui-selectmenu-icon ui-icon ui-icon-triangle-1-s"></span><span class="ui-selectmenu-text">Medium</span></span>
<span class="ui-selectmenu-icon ui-icon ui-icon-triangle-1-s"></span>
<span class="ui-selectmenu-text">Medium</span>
<span tabindex="0" id="speed-button" role="combobox" aria-expanded="false" aria-autocomplete="list" aria-owns="speed-menu" aria-haspopup="true" class="ui-selectmenu-button ui-button ui-widget ui-selectmenu-button-closed ui-corner-all" aria-activedescendant="ui-id-3" aria-labelledby="ui-id-3" aria-disabled="false"><span class="ui-selectmenu-icon ui-icon ui-icon-triangle-1-s"></span><span class="ui-selectmenu-text">Medium</span></span>
```

As you can see the initial tag `<select ... class="my-happy-decorated-class">` got hidden and applying any style to class **"my-happy-decorated-class"** is useless.

This is the point where jQuery UI-option `classes` comes to help! Just apply the option to the widget by using the same **selectmenu()** command and you'll get the class in certain place in the result code:

```
<script>
  $(function() {
      $("#speed").selectmenu();
      $("#speed").selectmenu({
        classes: {
            "ui-selectmenu-button-closed": "my-happy-decorated-class"
        }
      });
  });
</script>
```

**NOTE, that "ui-selectmenu-button-closed" is the default class**, that jQuery UI sets to resulting HTML-tag used for displaying the widget! Names of default classes of different parts of any widget you can see with F12 in your browser.

Resulting HTML-code will be:

```
    <select name="speed" id="speed" style="display: none;" class="my-happy-decorated-class">
                <option>Slower</option>
                <option>Slow</option>
                <option selected="selected">Medium</option>
                <option>Fast</option>
                <option>Faster</option>
            </select>
    <span tabindex="0" id="speed-button" role="combobox" aria-expanded="false" aria-autocomplete="list" aria-owns="speed-menu" aria-haspopup="true" class="ui-selectmenu-button ui-button ui-widget
ui-selectmenu-button-closed my-happy-decorated-class
ui-corner-all" aria-activedescendant="ui-id-3" aria-labelledby="ui-id-3" aria-disabled="false"><span class="ui-selectmenu-icon ui-icon ui-icon-triangle-1-s"></span><span class="ui-selectmenu-text">Medium</span></span>
    <span class="ui-selectmenu-icon ui-icon ui-icon-triangle-1-s"></span>
    <span class="ui-selectmenu-text">Medium</span>
    <span tabindex="0" id="speed-button" role="combobox" aria-expanded="false" aria-autocomplete="list" aria-owns="speed-menu" aria-haspopup="true" class="ui-selectmenu-button ui-button ui-widget ui-selectmenu-button-closed ui-corner-all" aria-activedescendant="ui-id-3" aria-labelledby="ui-id-3" aria-disabled="false"><span class="ui-selectmenu-icon ui-icon ui-icon-triangle-1-s"></span><span class="ui-selectmenu-text">Medium</span></span>
```

As you can see your class `my-happy-decorated-class`was added to the main visual resulting `span` of the widget and you are able to apply your styles to it.

Answer (score 0):

If you have multiple selects:

```
$("select").each(function(index, select) {
    $(select).selectmenu({
        create: function( event, ui ) {
            $(select).next().addClass($(select).attr('class'));
        },
        open: function( event, ui ) {
            // Maybe remove classes or whatever
        }
    });
});
```